# How to ignore a line containing a specific word using winmerge line filters?

Tags: regex, winmerge

I have many files containing following types of line -

```
* @version $Revision: 1.xxx
```

I want this type of line to be ignored while comparing using winmerge. I have tried with line filters. But, till not able to do that.
Can any one help me in this regard?

Comment: Did you try anything? Please post your regex here, or the question will be closed.

Comment: I have tried wirh this  - ^* @version

Comment: Check this Web site: http://regexfilterforw.sourceforge.net/. I see the line filter is not working properly.

Comment: Thanks, for reply. I have already checked that web site. But, it did not help me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After many tries the following regular expression is working for me -

```
^ \* @version \$Revision:
```

Answer (score 9):

You can actually do this with [**line filters**](http://manual.winmerge.org/Filters.html).

1. Select the filter option from the Selection Dialog
   [image: Select Filter]
2. Go to the Linefilters tab, enable line filters and then compose a regular expression that *matches* lines you want to filter out.
   [image: Line Filter]
3. In the results, it will highlight filtered lines in a different color, but it won't treat them as differences in the individual file or folder summary.
   [image: Filtered Result]

---

In your particular case, you'll want to find a regex pattern that matches your naming convention, but something like this should work:

[`@version \$Revision: \d\.\d*`](http://regexr.com/)

[image: Regexr Demo]

Comment: Mind blown. Thank you very useful :D

Answer (score 1):

Check the [WinMerge release notes](http://ftp.icpdas.com/pub/cd/indusoft/products/indusoft%20web%20studio%20v7.1/program%20files/redist/tools/mergetool/docs/releasenotes.html#issues):

> **Filters only applied when using full compare**.
>
> Line filtering is **only applied in folder compare** when using *Full
>   Contents-compare* method.
>
> If you are using any other compare method, line filters are not
>   applied. Files marked different in folder compare can get status
>   changed to identical when opening them to file compare.

So, you will not be able to use regex to filter out the lines that are open in right/left pane.

You will have to install and use 3rd party filters, e.g. http://regexfilterforw.sourceforge.net/.