# Filter JSON Property in WinMerge

Tags: regex, winmerge

I am using WinMerge to compare 2 JSON files and i want to filter out all lines with Date property

```
{       
  "Name": Foo,
  "Value": 1,       
  "Date": "2019-10-03T14:05:09.3261264",
}
```

I tried different Regex expressions (/[Date]/) but they dont work

Answer (score 0):

`[Date]` will match any character from the set you provided, that is any one of the letters `D`, `a`, `t` and `e`.

`"Date": ".+?"` would match the property you wanted (you can try it on [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/ke0vMP/2))

Comment: In what way is it not working, exactly? What should it be doing? What is it doing instead?

Comment: WinMerge is not filtering out the Lines with Date, it still mark them as difference. Think its not a problem with the regex expression....(Sorry for deleting my first reply)

Comment: Maybe the top voted answer on this question will help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29764428/how-to-ignore-a-line-containing-a-specific-word-using-winmerge-line-filters

Comment: Thank you but i doesnt help me, dont understand whats wrong https://imgur.com/ez4IsSQ